# creating directory using string c++

Tags: c++

The code in the last two methods below does not work. Please suggest some other way to make a directory using a string. window 10 visual studio 2015

```
string username="Ali";
string path = "c:/Backup/total data/" + username;
mkdir("c:/Backup");
mkdir("c:/Backup/total userdata");
_mkdir(path.str());            // method does not work     
mkdir(path.c_str());           // method does not work
system(path.c_str());          // method does not work
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: "*method not work*" is not a problem description. See [mcve].

Comment: window 10 visual studio

Comment: First, the directory separator on Windows is the backslash character ``\`` and not slash character. Second, a simple www search with `visual c++ create directory` listed as first result [CreateDirectory function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855.aspx). Visual Studio offers easy access to a very good help (MSDN - Microsoft Developer Network) explaining all library functions. You should make use of this help instead of asking Stack Overflow community for searching for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mkdir is deprecated, use _mkdir instead.
This works :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <direct.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string username = "Ali";
    string path = "c:\\Backup\\total data\\" + username;
    mkdir("c:\\Backup");
    mkdir("c:\\Backup\\total userdata");
    mkdir(path.c_str());     // method not work
    system(path.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this is OS's specific code and you haven't mentioned your OS so I am assuming windows.
For cross platform code take a look at boost/filesystem.hpp and boost::filesystem::create_directory
Make sure you have the appropriate priviledges (run program as admin)

Comment: _mkdir error c3867

Comment: window 10 visual studio

Comment: @ZakaAhmadChishti I am aso using windows 10 and msvc 2015. using mkdir gets me error : C4996 'mkdir': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _mkdir. On the other hand using _mkdir works fine in my case.

Comment: Please share some example you try...... and it works completly

Comment: @ZakaAhmadChishti I posted full code

Comment: Thanks so much it works.........